# Mute / blank an amplifier fast

Tags: rf, switches, circuit-design

I would like to build a circuit to mute an RF Class A amplifier to supress noise while I am not transmitting. I transmit ~20 us long pulses at ~1-5 MHz. In the time between the RF pulses, I would like to suppress the noise generated by the amplifier. The peak power is 300 watts (50 Ohm system, meaning I reach ~180 Vp during the pulse). However, the duty cycle is low, typically < 5%. Ideally switching times (arm & disarm) should be around 1 us. I have a 5 V AWG marker signal that I could use to control the blanking circuit.

Do you have a circuit idea for me?

Peter

PS: The amplifier can handle reflection.

Comment: Where exactly does the noise come from? assuming a 300 W power stage doesn't have immensely much gain, I'd have expected that just tying its input to a DC voltage (e.g. 0 V) would get rid of all noise (but the noise figure), seeing that you're AC coupling this, right?

Comment: Show the rf amplifier schematic please.